# C# Error al ejecutar update con with

Tags: c#, postgresql, c#-8.0

Tengo la siguente consulta:

```js
WITH lectura AS (
    SELECT * FROM antenas_registros 
    WHERE tag = 'tag' 
    ORDER BY ID DESC 
    LIMIT 1
),
actualiza AS (
    SELECT 
        IIF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lectura) > 0, 
                (('2021-08-11 11:18:13' - (SELECT salida FROM lectura)) < '00:03:00'), 
                FALSE) AS actu
)
UPDATE antenas_registros 
SET salida = IIF((SELECT actu FROM actualiza LIMIT 1), '2021-08-11 11:18:13'::TIMESTAMP, (SELECT salida FROM lectura)::TIMESTAMP)
WHERE tag = 'tag' AND
         salida = (SELECT salida FROM lectura)::TIMESTAMP
```

Al ejecutar la consulta con navicat funciona correctamente, pero al correrla desde mi programa en c# me dispara el siguiente error:

> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

la conexión esta abierta para la instancia de ejecución de esta Query

```
public static bool Modificar(Registro obj, out int recodsAffecteds, double difEnMinutos = 3) {
        string fechaSalida = obj.Salida.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").InsertStringInSQL();
        string tag = obj.Tag.InsertStringInSQL();

        TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(difEnMinutos);
        string diferencia = (((t.Hours <= 9) ? "0" : "") + t.Hours + ":" + ((t.Minutes <= 9) ? "0" : "") + t.Minutes + ":" + ((t.Seconds <= 9) ? "0" : "") + t.Seconds).InsertStringInSQL();
        Command cmd = new Command {
            ActiveConnection = _Connection,
            CommandText = "WITH lectura AS (\n" +
                          " SELECT * FROM antenas_registros \n" +
                         $" WHERE tag = {tag} \n" +
                          " ORDER BY ID DESC \n" +
                          " LIMIT 1\n" +
                          "),\n" +
                          "actualiza AS (\n" +
                          " SELECT \n" +
                          "     IIF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lectura) > 0, \n" +
                         $"             (({fechaSalida} - (SELECT salida FROM lectura)) < {diferencia}), \n" +
                          "             FALSE) AS actu\n" +
                          ")\n" +
                          "UPDATE antenas_registros \n" +
                         $"SET salida = IIF((SELECT actu FROM actualiza LIMIT 1), {fechaSalida}::TIMESTAMP, (SELECT salida FROM lectura)::TIMESTAMP)\n" +
                         $"WHERE tag = {tag} AND\n" +
                          "      salida = (SELECT salida FROM lectura)::TIMESTAMP"
        };
        recodsAffecteds = cmd.ExecuteNonQueryCount();
        return recodsAffecteds > 0;
    }
```

Este es el código que se ejecuto para realizar la consulta

Comment: ¿Dónde está `_Connection`? ¿Seguro que tienes la conexión abierta? ¿Podrías mostrar un poco más de tu código por favor?

Comment: Coincido con @fredyfx, puede ser un tema con _Connection. Ahora si no lo es, creo que ese Update igual podes hacerlo en 3 partes, recuperas Lectura, luego el Actualiza y haces un Update normal con los datos que te vinieron en esas dos consultas, Hasta quedaria mejor para mi gusto